# How do I iterate until a fixed point in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, iteration, fixed-point-iteration

I'm frequently in the position that my code reads like so:

```
(iterate improve x)
```

And I'm looking for the first value that no longer is an improvement over the previous. Neither `filter` nor `take-while` lend themselves to an obvious solution. However, I'm hesitant to write out:

```
(loop [current x
       next (improve x)]
  (if (= current next)
    current
    (recur next (improve next))))
```

or:

```
(let [improvements (iterate improve x)]
  (->> (map vector improvements (rest improvements))
    (filter (partial apply =))
    (ffirst)))
```

Because at some point this is becoming repetitive and surely fixed point iteration is such a basic task that there must be some kind of library support somewhere, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and `reduced` to stop when necessary. [reduced](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/reduced) wraps the argument in a special object, which `reduce` is designed to look for and stop processing immediately returning the wrapped value.

```
(def vals (iterate improve x))

(reduce #(if (= %1 %2) (reduced %1) %2) vals)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `drop-while` then `first`:

```
(defn still-improving? [[x y]]
  ...)

(->> st
     (iterate transition)
     (partition 2 1)
     (drop-while still-improving?)
     ffirst)
```